# How can I generate a diff patch file for only committed files?

Tags: git

Say I'm working on my local master branch. I change file A and file B. But the changes in file B are just debugging stuff, and I don't want to commit them. So I stage file A and run `git commit`.

Now I want to generate a patch file against origin/master. But when I run the below command the generated patched file contains both my changes to file A and B. Is there a way to generate a patch for the currently committed files in my local master vs. origin/master? (A patch that only includes changes I've committed to my local branch.)

```
git diff -M --full-index origin/master > ../diff.patch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and most-obviously correct answer derives straight from your intention in your question:

> Now I want to generate a patch file against origin/master.

**If you want a single patch,** regardless of how many commits you have made, simply diff the `origin/master` tree against your current commit:

```
$ git diff -M --full-index origin/master HEAD
```

(I included `-M` and `--full-index` here because you did in your sample command.  Note that you can make `-M` the default by setting `diff.renames = true` in your [`git config` settings](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).)

**If you want patches made from each commit,** in a format that `git am` handles, you can use [`git format-patch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html).  Because it's designed to do this sort of thing, it takes a single "what commit do they have" identifier, hence:

```
$ git format-patch origin/master
```

means the same thing as:

```
$ git format-patch origin/master..HEAD
```

so either of these can be used interchangeably.  See [the `git format-patch` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html) for additional details.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
 git format-patch -1 HEAD
```

Assuming you only want the most recent commit.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps. It may help.

1. Do `git stash` to clear the repository, i.e., file B modification will go off.
2. Generate the patch
3. Load file B from the stash using `git stash apply`
4. Remove the stash (optional but stash object is not required)